# Print and Email Images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-postgresql, pg

How to print and email images in ruby-on-rails-3?

My code is here:

```
<%= image_tag('logo.png', :height => "100px",:width => "200px",:alt => "Software") %>
```

It is not displaying the image.

If anyone knows how to display image please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't tell what is the actual error but I guess this is a path issue. So far I guess, it will produce a relative path. So, try this:

```
<%= image_tag(image_path('logo.png'), :height => "100px",:width => "200px",:alt => "Software") %>
```

Comment: I am not getting any error. Image is not displaying. actually i am printing one page in pdf format there i want to display that image. but the image is not displaying.